# Prepending the url path in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, mod-rewrite

Generally in CodeIgniter we get this structure of URL :

```
domain/controller/function
```

So suppose I went to some user's profile then URL would be :

```
domain/user/profile/username
```

How can I change that to

```
domain/username
```

OR even more better if

```
domain/u/username
```

where the middle part is what i decide.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: `_remap()` should do the [trick](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can user routes.php for this purpose
Suppose you want a url like

```
domain/u/username
```

Then in routes.php you can specify the routing rule like below:

```
$route['u/(:any)'] = "user/profile/$1";
```

This specifies that if a url comes like '/u/anyvalue' then execute user/profile/$1
where $1 will be the anyvalue